# Changing UI with updated data values in Meteor app

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am currently developing an offline only mobile app with Meteor. I use HTML5 local storage for persistence.

I have a template and a variable inside it, an integer

```
<head>
  <title>counter-a</title>
</head>

<body>

  {{> counts}}
</body>

<template name="counts">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p id="counts">You've pressed the button {{counts}} times.</p>
</template>
```

I have the helper for that template to set the template variable:

```
    Template.counts.helpers({
    counts: function () {
      return parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counts"));
    }
  });
```

What changes the value of the items value in the local storage is an event on the template:

```
    Template.counts.events({
    'click button#increase': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      localStorage.setItem("counts", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counts")) + 1);
        //instead can set counts in helper taht s template var to new value in localStorage.
        counts();

    },
});
```

And what changes the user interface with the updated value in the local storage was a `document.getlEmentById('counts').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("counts");`

All happens in an: `if(Meteor.isClient)` and no `if(Meteor.isServer)` exists.

What I wonder is if there is a way of setting not the `innerHTML` of the html element in which the template variable was written but the value of the template variable with code and let Meteor renew the gui automatically as it does with the data sources which it regards as reactive, like db or session? How to reach that template variable manually as Meteor does it automatically in reactive jobs it does?

Would that be the good practice in that job? Since my helper counts has no business except at the beginning in the use of `innerHTML` setting.

Comment: Did you figure out how to visually respond to reactive change in Template data? I have a very similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You kind of want to use `ReactiveVar` from the `reactive-var` package, but that will not store the variable in local storage for you; you'll need to do that yourself each time you set the variable to a new value.

I imagine someone has built a package for your specific purpose, and [dispatch:stored-var](https://atmospherejs.com/dispatch/stored-var) seems to do that, but I've never used it, so I don't know.